# Searchable drop down list for rails 3.2.8?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

On new order form, a user needs to select a customer from a drop down list which contains dozens of customers and is hard to find and select by scrolling up and down. That's why we want to build a searchable `drop down list`. When a user enter a few letters of customer's name, the drop down list filters out all others and is left with only the names of the customers containing the letters just keyed in. We are using `simple_form` and `rails 3.2.8`. One way we can do is to add a `text box` for entering search string and call `ajax` to load the drop down list accordingly. This requires additional text field which is redundant. Is there any solution which a user can directly type in drop down box and the list filters out accordingly? Thanks.

Comment: [You're welcome.](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the JQuery UI autocomplete combobox.  It provides both drop down functionality as well as search (autocomplete) functionality.  It should work just fine with simple_form.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

The best example i've found of implementation is:
http://babinho.net/2011/05/autocomplete-fields-in-rails-3-1-with-jquery-ui/

Comment: It is what　we are looking for. Thanks. BTW Do you happen to have an rails integration example?

Comment: Updated with a website detailing out to use it.

Comment: Just duplicate the example by babinho. The example seems missing some piece to function. It does not have the views.

Comment: @RichOnRails - thank you - the documentation says that: this is not a supported or even complete widget. Its purely for demoing what autocomplete can do with a bit of customization - what do they mean by this?

Answer (score 1):

I have quite good success with the Soulmate gem found https://github.com/seatgeek/soulmate. 
There's a well-written article which describes the gem too: http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/11/23/finding-your-soulmate-autocomplete-with-redis-in-rails-3-1

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already use (or don't want to use) jQuery UI in your project, you can use select2: http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Comment: There is "//= require jquery_ui" in the application.js. Did you mean select2 conflict with jquery_ui?

Comment: Then you already use jQuery UI, so it's fine to also use its autocomplete widget. I suggested select2 as an alternative in case you don't use jQuert UI, or don't want to use it. There is no conflict issues as far as I know. You're just adding extra bloat to your project's javascript, if you use both.