# RailsAdmin with polymorphic associations

Tags: polymorphic-associations, rails-admin

I am using, Rails 4.1, RailsAdmin 0.8.1 and Mongoid 5.0.1.  I defined has_many / belongs_to relationship between Products and Pictures RailsAdmin generates a Product dropdown in the Picture model.  I can choose Product or I can search for Product.

I implemented polymorphic association between Products, Pictures and Employees.  Now when I edit Picture I have 2 dropdowns - to choose type (Product or Employee) and 2nd to choose the actual record.

The problem is RailsAdmin is trying to load the entire Employee or Product list into 2nd dropdown.  I have many thousands Employees and eventually it timesout.  Any ideas how to search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown lists are populated when page is loaded. The second dropdown will have everything you send during page loading (before you have chosen 'type' in first dropdown).

What I think you want can be achieved using ajax to send a request when first dropdown is selected, retrieve the values and then populate your second dropdown list.

Some sources you can read. [link1](http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2013/12/come-implementare-in-rails-4-delle-dropdown-dipendenti-con-script-jquery-non-intrusivo/) [link2](http://railsguides.net/cascading-selects-with-ajax-in-rails/) [link3](https://github.com/radar/guides/blob/master/dependent-select-box.md)

Comment: But how do I modify the 2nd dropdown (selecting specific record) to have a searchbox instead of just dropdown?

Comment: You will find many implementations of that in jquery. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926330/searchable-drop-down-list-for-rails-3-2-8 for some sources.

Comment: I have also added some some sources for implementation of 'dependent select' in the answer.